# OR opertor ignores AND operator MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, operators

see the query below i want all those records where status is either using or offering and userid is not equals to 1 and coursecode is cs3333

```
SELECT c.`id` AS courseid,
    c.`userid` AS userid,
    c.`coursecode`,
    m.`title`,
    s.`sem_name`,
    p.`professor`,
    st.`status`,
    a.`author_name`,
    q.`quality`,
    m.`comments`,
    m.`price`,
    m.`material`
FROM sc_courses c
    JOIN sc_c_materials m
    ON c.`id`=m.`courseid`

    JOIN sc_semesters s
    ON s.`id`=c.`semid`

    JOIN sc_professors p
    ON c.`profid`=p.`id`

    JOIN sc_status st
    ON c.`statusid`=st.`id`

    LEFT JOIN sc_authors a
    ON m.`authorid`=a.`id`

    JOIN sc_quality q
    ON m.`qualityid`=q.`id`
WHERE st.`status` = "offering" OR st.`status` = "using"  AND c.`userid` != "1" AND c.`coursecode` = "CS3333";
```

the query is running but it ignores both the and operators the above query return all records where userid is 1 and coursecode is not equal to cs3333 but i dont want these records plz tell me what am i doing wrong????

Comment: `WHERE st.status = "offering" OR st.status = "using"  AND c.userid != "1" AND c.coursecode = "CS3333"` --- tell what do you think this condition means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need brackets

```
WHERE (st.`status` = "offering" OR st.`status` = "using")  AND c.`userid` != "1" AND c.`coursecode` = "CS3333";
```

Comment: Everything inside the brackets is evaluated first, and then what is outside the brackets will be added to the filtering. So you are first or all asking that the status must be "offering" or "using", and if this is satisfied, then you add the rest of the filters to the query. If you mix an OR in with lots of ANDs, the results are unpredictable without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

That is because priority. You should place `( .. )` to change order of comparison.

```
(st.`status` = "offering" OR st.`status` = "using")  
AND c.`userid` != "1" 
AND c.`coursecode` = "CS3333"
```

Answer (score 0):

opss stupid mistake here it is working with this query

```
SELECT c.`id` AS courseid,
    c.`userid` AS userid,
    c.`coursecode`,
    m.`title`,
    s.`sem_name`,
    p.`professor`,
    st.`status`,
    a.`author_name`,
    q.`quality`,
    m.`comments`,
    m.`price`,
    m.`material`
FROM sc_courses c
    JOIN sc_c_materials m
    ON c.`id`=m.`courseid`

    JOIN sc_semesters s
    ON s.`id`=c.`semid`

    JOIN sc_professors p
    ON c.`profid`=p.`id`

    JOIN sc_status st
    ON c.`statusid`=st.`id`

    LEFT JOIN sc_authors a
    ON m.`authorid`=a.`id`

    JOIN sc_quality q
    ON m.`qualityid`=q.`id`
WHERE c.`userid` != "1" AND c.`coursecode` = "CS3333" AND st.`status` = "offering" OR 
    c.`userid` != "1" AND c.`coursecode` = "CS3333" AND st.`status` = "using";
```